# Links in view - wrong language selection

Tags: views, navigation, i18n-l10n

Ok, I'm not sure where should I go with this problem, so forgive me if this is not the exactly best place for it.

I've created multilanguage site, of course, got many problems, but solved them all - so far. Now, when I launched german version of a site, I realized there's a problem. I have a content type of X, made a view to display a page containing table with all the X content types. Just usual listing. The link to it is in the menu, displaying only for german language. So far all in that version worked fine, but now I see there's a problem.

Content X - link for adding it is on german version only and while adding it, it works fine. But when I'm on my view page, when I click on any title of content X type (which is a link of course) I'm getting redirected to default site language. And it should stay on german version. I can't think of any ideas, so: what is wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Anyone? Really?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8526/default-language-not-working-properly) after one day struggling with same issue:

- goto: Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Languages.
- select the 'DETECTION AND SELECTION' tab.
- Un-check all except 'URL' and 'default'. Keep 'URL' on top of 'default'