# Default language on Language list page

Tags: 10

I have just installed a brand new drupal 10 website. My goal is to make french its default language and add English as another available language.
For that :

- I selected FRENCH as default language on the first step of the Drupal installation.
- I enabled the following modules :
  Configuration translation
  Content Translation
  Interface Translation
  Language
- I added a new language "English" here /fr/admin/config/regional/language
- I checked Enable interface translation to English for the english language.

When I am on /admin/config/regional/language, if I click on Translate next to French, I am redirected to /admin/config/regional/language/edit/fr/translate and I see that French (original) is the default language.
However, if I am on /admin/config/regional/language, if I click on Translate next to ENGLISH, I am redirected to /admin/config/regional/language/edit/en/translate and I see that ENGLISH (original)    is the default language.
I can't understand why the default language is ENGLISH when I edit the english language ? shouldn't it always be French ?

**/admin/config/regional/language/edit/fr/translate** gives:
[image]

**/admin/config/regional/language/edit/en/translate** gives : [image]

Comment: There isn’t really a question here. This may actually be a bug. This old question may be useful https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8526/default-language-not-working-properly

Comment: What you are seeing is is the "original" language of the language configuration object, NOT the default language of your website. A language is not just boolean "is enabled yes or no", it also has some additional meta data like e.g. direction (left-to-right). That configuration meta data was originally provided in english.

Comment: @Hudri , yes but on some other D8 websites that were initially installed in french like mine, I see that french is the  original language of the english language configuration object, that's why on /admin/config/regional/language/edit/en they add Anglais because it's the language name in the french default language and on /admin/config/regional/language/edit/en/translate/en/edit they add label = English because it's the english translation of the label Anglais. This is the intended behaviour.

Comment: but in my case, english is the original language of english so I am supposed to label the language as english not Anglais cz right now it's like i'm saying Anglais is the label of the english language in English and it's not correct.

Comment: ideally, i want to label the english language as Anglais in its english translation but the french should remain its original language. so i would say Anglais is the label of the english language in french (the site's default lang).

Comment: I think it's a bug like @cilefen pointed out

Comment: This is not a bug, you can have config objects with different langcodes. If you are unhappy with this one, change it with `drush cedit language.entity.en`